# Not able to encrypt a string with a public key in Protractor

Tags: protractor, jsencrypt

I am trying call the encrypt function mentioned below:

```
var encryptor = require("./jsencrypt.js");
this.encrypt = function () {
  var key="LxVtiqZV6g2D493gDBfG0BfV6sAhteG6hOCAu48qO00Z99OpiaIG5vZxVtiqZV8C7bpwIDAQAB";
  encryptor = new JSEncrypt();
  encryptor.setPublicKey(key);
  var newString = encryptor.encrypt('Password');
  console.log("Encrypted password =",newString);
}
```

Initially I was getting Reference Error for undefined JSEncrypt.
So I downoaded *jsencrypt.js* file and added `var encryptor = require("./jsencrypt.js");`at the begining. 
Now I am getting following error:

```
Message:
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
Stacktrace:
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
at e:\Praveen Data\Projects\ECP\CentralRegistryUI\TestScripts\Utils\jsencrypt.js:73:13
at Object.<anonymous> (e:\Praveen Data\Projects\ECP\CentralRegistryUI\TestScripts\Utils\jsencrypt.js:4342:3)
at require (module.js:385:17)
```

Tried using windows.navigator in jsencrypt.js, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my colleague helped me with the solution.
So here I have a function for encryption:

```
this.initializeEncryptedPassword = () => {
    //console.log("before calling encrypt... ");
    browser.executeScript(() => {
      //console.log("Starting to return encryptor...");
      return window.loginEncryptor.encrypt(window.loginPassword);
    }).then((encryptedPassword) => {
      this.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
    });
    //console.log("after calling encrypt...");
}
```

This function is being called by:

```
export default class Encryptor {

  constructor($window, $http) {
    'ngInject';
    this.encryptor = new $window.JSEncrypt();
    //Need to use HTTP here instead of resource since the resource does not return plain text.
    //Getting Public Key by hitting a rest uri.
    $http({method: "GET", url: "/xyz/authenticate"}).success((item) => {
        this.encryptor.setPublicKey(item);
        //set the current encryptor on the window so that testing can use it
        $window.loginEncryptor = this.encryptor;
    });
  }

  encryptPassword(credentials) {
    credentials.password = this.encryptor.encrypt(credentials.password);
  }

}
```

Hope this help others.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor tests are not run in browser environment but in node.js, because of that navigator object is not available there. JSEncrypt relies on it to work on the client side across different browsers and versions.

It's referenced in many places in the JSEncrypt code so my best bet would be to either switch to a server side encryption library that would work for you or if not possible mock a global navigator json object with all expected properties/methods as if it was a Chrome browser - node.js runs on chrome's js engine so should work fine.

Comment: Thank you Tom. As you mentoned, I will try to global navigator json object and make it work. I shall update this post with solution code if I am able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

before require('jsencrypt') you can write first:

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
const { window } = jsdom;
global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;
global.navigator ={userAgent: 'node.js'};

const { JSEncrypt } = require('jsencrypt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock by doing the following:

global.navigator = { appName: 'protractor' };

global.window = {};

const JSEncrypt = require('JSEncrypt').default;